# How can I make transient/one-off state changes to a React component from one of its ancestors?

Tags: reactjs

I want to modify the state of a child component in React from a parent component a couple levels above it.
The child component is a [`react-table`](https://react-table.tanstack.com/) with pagination.
My use case is changing the data in the table with some client-side JS filtering.

The problem is, the table uses internal state to keep track of which page is being shown, and does not fully update in response to my filtering.
It is smart enough to know how much data it contains, but not smart enough to update the page it is on.
So, it might correctly say "Showing items 21-30 of 85", and then the user filters the data down to only four total items, and the table will say "Showing items 21-30 of 4".

I tried implementing something like [what the FAQ suggests for manual state control](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/faq#how-can-i-manually-control-the-table-state), but that caused its own problem.
I was passing the new page index in as a prop, and that did set the page correctly, but it broke the ability for the user to navigate between pages, because any changes were immediately overwritten by the value of the prop.
Those instructions seem to work for a situation where *all* page index control gets handled by the parent, but not when some control should still be retained by the pagination mechanism.

**I think what I need is an exposed function that lets me modify the value of the table's `state.pageIndex` as a one-off instead of passing a permanent prop. Is there a way to do that? Or any other way to solve my underlying problem?**

Code follows. I apologize in advance I couldn't make this a real [SSCCE](https://www.sscce.org/), it was just too complicated, I tried to at least follow the spirit of SSCCEs as much as I could.

My page that lists stuff for the user looks like this:

```
// ...
const [searchTerms, setSearchTerms] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
// ...
const handleFilterRequestFromUser = function (searchTerms): void {
    // ...
    setSearchTerms(processedSearchTerms);
};
// ...
const visibleData = useMemo(() => {
    // ...
}, [searchTerms]);
// ...
return (
    <div>
        // ...
        <ImmediateParentOfTable
            id={"Results"}
            visibleData={visibleData} // User actions can affect the size of this
            // ...
        >
        // ...
    </div>
);

export default ListDatabaseResults;
```

Here's `ImmediateParentOfTable`:

```
import { Table, Pagination } from "@my-company/react";

// ...

return (
    <Table
        id={id}
        pagination={{
                render: (
                    dataSize,
                    {
                        pageCount,
                        pageOptions,
                        // ...
                    }
                ) => (
                    <Pagination
                        dataSize={dataSize}
                        pageCount={pageCount}
                        pageOptions={pageOptions}
                        gotoPage={gotoPage}
                        previousPage={previousPage}
                        nextPage={nextPage}
                        setPageSize={setPageSize}
                        canPreviousPage={canPreviousPage}
                        canNextPage={canNextPage}
                        pageIndex={pageIndex}
                        pageSize={pageSize}
                        pageSizeOptions={[10, 20, 50, 100]}
                    />
                ),
                manual: {
                    onPageChange: ({
                        pageIndex,
                        pageSize,
                    }: {
                        pageIndex: number;
                        pageSize: number;
                    }) => {
                        setPageIndex(pageIndex);
                        setPageSize(pageSize);
                    },
                    rowCount,
                    pageCount: tablePageCount,
                },
                isLoading: !!dataLoading,
        }}
    />
);
```

The custom `Table` inside `@my-company/react` (already in use in other places, so, difficult to modify):

```
import {
    CellProps,
    Column,
    Hooks,
    Row,
    SortingRule,
    TableState,
    useFlexLayout,
    usePagination,
    UsePaginationInstanceProps,
    UsePaginationState,
    useRowSelect,
    useSortBy,
    useTable,
} from 'react-table';

// ...

export interface TableProps<D extends Record<string, unknown>> {
    id: string;
    // ...
    pagination?: Pagination<D>;
    pageIndexOverride?: number; // This is the new prop I added that breaks pagination
}

const Table = <D extends Record<string, unknown>>({
    id,
    columns,
    data,
    // ...
    pageIndexOverride,
}: TableProps<D>): JSX.Element => {
    const {
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize, sortBy },
            // ...
    } = useTable(
        {
        columns,
        data,
        autoResetPage,
        initialState,
        useControlledState: (state) => {
            return React.useMemo(
            () => ({
                ...state,
                pageIndex: pageIndexOverride || state.pageIndex, // This always resets page index to the prop value, so changes from the pagination bar no longer work
            }),
            [state],
            );
        },
    // ...
```

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What it sounds like to me is that you had a functioning table but with `autoResetPage: false` so the pageIndex wasn't updating when your filters did. Why not, in the Table component, have a `useEffect` hook that changes the page when your data does, or something similar (pass down your filters and reset when those change, or maybe even just let it autoResetPage)? Understandably, since this seems like a very complex setup, it might not be the best solution, but it's worth revisiting the basics.

Comment: It could very well be an XY problem, I don't understand enough to say for sure. The table implementation I'm using is code I don't directly control, and is in production use in other places at my company, so I'm reluctant to change much about it. I have a stopgap workaround that separates the displayed page index from the page index in state. After I posted this question, I thought of doing something with React Hooks's `useImperativeHandle` to allow one-off changes to state. I'll have to re-read about `autoResetPage` to see if I missed something useful, now that you mention it.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered a similar problem with `react-table` where most of my functionality (pagination, sorting, filtering) is done server-side and of course when a filter is changed I must set the `pageIndex` back to `0` to rectify the same problem you have mentioned.

Unfortunately, as you have discovered, controlled state in `v7` of `react-table` is both poorly documented and apparently just completely non-functional.

I will note that the example code you linked from the docs

```
 const [controlledPageIndex, setControlledPage] = React.useState(0)

 

 useTable({

   useControlledState: state => {

     return React.useMemo(

       () => ({

         ...state,

         pageIndex: controlledPageIndex,

       }),

       [state, controlledPageIndex]

     )

   },

 })
```

is actually invalid. `controlledPageIndex` cannot be used as a dep in that `useMemo` because it is in the outer scope and is accessed through closure. Mutating it will do nothing, which is actually noted by eslint `react/exhaustive-deps` rule so it's quite surprising that this made it into the docs as a way of accomplishing things. There are more reasons why it is unusable, but the point is that you can forget using `useControlledState` for anything.

My suggestion is to use the `stateReducer` table option and `dispatch` a custom action that will do what you need it to. The table reducer actions can have arbitrary payloads so you can do pretty much whatever you want. ajkl2533 in the github issues used this approach for row selection (https://github.com/TanStack/react-table/issues/3142#issuecomment-822482864)

```
const reducer = (newState, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'deselectAllRows') {
    return { ...newState, selectedRowIds: {} };
   }

   return newState;
}

...

const { dispatch, ... } = useTable({ stateReducer: reducer }, ...);

const handleDeselectAll = () => {
  dispatch({ type: 'deselectAllRows' });
}
```

It will require getting access to the `dispatch` from the `useTable` hook though.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting using the `stateReducer` prop and providing an example. It solved my issue. Strange for the official docs of v7 to include a piece of code that doesn't work (with `useControlledState`)...